# `brew install infer` error while updating infer

Tags: ocaml, macos-sierra, osx-elcapitan, opam, facebook-infer

I recently updated facebook infer on my work laptop, and am trying to update infer on my personal laptop. It installed without an issue on my work laptop, but I am getting an error (see below) on my personal laptop. Both have opam 1.2.2 and ocaml 4.03.0 installed. If I execute `opam init --comp=VERSION`, I see that everything is already up-to-date. Any ideas why `brew install infer` could be failing?

```
[User]-MacBook-Pro:~ [User]$ brew install infer
==> Using the sandbox
==> Downloading https://github.com/facebook/infer/releases/download/v0.9.2/infer
Already downloaded: /Users/[User]/Library/Caches/Homebrew/infer-0.9.2.tar.xz
==> ./build-infer.sh all --yes
Last 15 lines from /Users/[User]/Library/Logs/Homebrew/infer/01.build-infer.sh:

initializing opam... 
Checking for available remotes: rsync and local, git.
  - you won't be able to use mercurial repositories unless you install the hg
    command on your system.
  - you won't be able to use darcs repositories unless you install the darcs
    command on your system.

[WARNING] Recommended external solver aspcud not found.
[ERROR] No OCaml compiler found in path. You should use:

            opam init --comp=VERSION

[ERROR] Initialisation failed
OpamGlobals.Exit(66)

READ THIS: https://git.io/brew-troubleshooting
If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/brew):
  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues

These open issues may also help:
infer 0.9.3 https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/5130
```

My work laptop is on OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.6, and my personal laptop is on macOS Sierra Version 10.12.

https://github.com/facebook/infer/issues/467

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved in Infer version 0.9.4.1